# Neo4j newsfeed adjustment

Tags: neo4j

I am using this example, http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html, to maintain newsfeeds for my users. So I use the following to post a status update:

```
MATCH (me)
WHERE me.name='Bob'
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[r:STATUS]-(secondlatestupdate)
DELETE r
CREATE (me)-[:STATUS]->(latest_update { text:'Status',date:123 })
WITH latest_update, collect(secondlatestupdate) AS seconds
FOREACH (x IN seconds | CREATE (latest_update)-[:NEXT]->(x))
RETURN latest_update.text AS new_status
```

And the following to fetch them:

```
MATCH (me { name: 'Joe' })-[rels:FRIEND*0..1]-(myfriend)
WHERE ALL (r IN rels WHERE r.status = 'CONFIRMED')
WITH myfriend
MATCH (myfriend)-[:STATUS|:NEXT*0..2]-(statusupdates)
RETURN myfriend.name AS name, statusupdates.date AS date, statusupdates.text AS text
ORDER BY statusupdates.date DESC LIMIT 3
```

This looks straightforward. The newsfeed will contain latest 2 status updates from my friends. But let's say we want to select statusupdates that fullfill only a certain criteria. For example:

```
MATCH (myfriend)-[:STATUS|:NEXT*0..2]-(statusupdates {type: "photo"})
```

This seems to be working. But this doesn't work if for example a user posts 4 status updates in a short time with the latest 2 updates of a different type.

Let's say that out of the 4 updates, the latest 2 are of type "url" and the 2 before that are of type "photo". The above newsfeed fetching code simply ignores this user because it sees that the latest 2 status updates from this user are not of type "photo" even if all 4 posts are newer than posts from other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get some data in database that represents your situation:

```
CREATE (n1:Update {id: 1, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n2:Update {id: 2, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n3:Update {id: 3, type: 'photo'})
CREATE (n4:Update {id: 4, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n5:Update {id: 5, type: 'photo'})
CREATE (n6:Update {id: 6, type: 'url'})

CREATE (n1)<-[:NEXT]-(n2)<-[:NEXT]-(n3)<-[:NEXT]-(n4)<-[:NEXT]-(n5)<-[:NEXT]-(n6)
CREATE (user:User)-[:STATUS]->(n1)
```

Your query:

```
MATCH (user:User) WITH user
MATCH (user)-[:STATUS|:NEXT*0..2]-(statuses:Update {type: "photo"}) 
RETURN user, statuses
```

If we execute it, then as you said we get '(no rows)'.

Possible solution:

```
MATCH (user:User) WITH user
MATCH (user)-[:STATUS|:NEXT*]-(statuses:Update {type: "photo"}) 
RETURN statuses LIMIT 2
```

Cons of such solution: we will traverse all statuses, and only then apply `LIMIT` filter.

Traversing is quite fast operation. What you can do is - combine traverse depth with `LIMIT` clause. For example:

```
MATCH (user:User) WITH user
MATCH (user)-[:STATUS|:NEXT*0..100]-(statuses:Update {type: "photo"}) 
RETURN statuses LIMIT 2
```

This is compromise between needed data and performance.

But! Alternatively, what you can do is - create additional relationship chains for separate update types.

Example:

```
CREATE (n1:Update {id: 1, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n2:Update {id: 2, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n3:Update {id: 3, type: 'photo'})
CREATE (n4:Update {id: 4, type: 'url'})
CREATE (n5:Update {id: 5, type: 'photo'})
CREATE (n6:Update {id: 6, type: 'url'})

CREATE (n1)<-[:NEXT]-(n2)<-[:NEXT]-(n3)<-[:NEXT]-(n4)<-[:NEXT]-(n5)<-[:NEXT]-(n6)
CREATE (n3)<-[:NEXT_PHOTO]-(n5)
CREATE (user:User)-[:LAST_STATUS {feedType: 'main'}]->(n1)
CREATE (user:User)-[:LAST_STATUS {feedType: 'photo'}]->(n3)
```

Pros: you can easily acquire necessary data in most performant way.

Cons: data model in database became more complicated and requires additional maintenance.